# Setting Vim whitespace preferences by filetype

Tags: vim, whitespace, preferences

At my work, I am required to follow the house style for indentation, which goes as follows:

- 2 spaces when coding html and ruby
- tabs when coding javascript, with tabwidth=4 recommended

What is the best way to specify different whitespace preferences per filetype?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing Vim indentation behavior by file type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158968/changing-vim-indentation-behavior-by-file-type)

Comment: All these answers just made me more confused. The problem is that the options are up to preference. The accepted answer has a nice syntax though. This was an excellent guide: http://vimcasts.org/transcripts/2/en/

Answer (score 259, accepted):

there are many ways, but here's a simple, easy to understand way. add these lines to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType html setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2
autocmd FileType ruby setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal ts=4 sts=4 sw=4
```

Comment: ts = 'number of spaces that <Tab> in file uses'

sts = 'number of spaces that <Tab> uses while editing'

sw = 'number of spaces to use for (auto)indent step' 

for details see: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickref.html#option-list

Comment: I needed to append expandtab at least for ruby, see answer by 'too much php' here

Answer (score 91):

Peter's answer is straightforward enough, but unfortunately the options aren't right. You need to use the following options instead:

```
autocmd Filetype html setlocal ts=2 sw=2 expandtab
autocmd Filetype ruby setlocal ts=2 sw=2 expandtab
autocmd Filetype javascript setlocal ts=4 sw=4 sts=0 noexpandtab
```

Also note:

- You can make vim show tab characters by using `:set list`.
- Once you have the tab/space options set correctly, you can make vim repair the file (replace spaces with tabs or vice versa) using the `:retab!` command.

Comment: What's the benefit of `expandtab` over `sts=2`

Comment: @JamesMcMahon expandtab expands all tabs to spaces. sts (softtabstop) inserts spaces and tabs for indents: as many tabs as will fit in the indent based on the size of tabstop, and then spaces after that. Of course, if expandtab is on, all the tabs that get inserted are converted to spaces.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562336/tab-vs-space-preferences-in-vim might help further. Without expand tab, Peter's answer would insert tabs that are 2 chars wide, not spaces.

Answer (score 38):

+1 to Peter's answer, but Vim provides another solution as well. If you want to do something more complicated than a single `setlocal`, like setting up a whole bunch of options, commands, and mappings at once, then vim's filetype plugin feature comes to the rescue.

You need to have `filetype plugin on` or `filetype plugin indent on` in your `.vimrc`, and then to create a plugin for e.g. ruby you can create `~/.vim/ftplugin/ruby.vim`. Technically you can use any commands you like in here, to be run when a Ruby file is loaded, but the recommended ones include `setlocal`, `map <buffer>`, `command -buffer`, and defining functions. Lots more information is in the User Guide; if you're pretty familiar with scripting vim then jump to `:help 41.11`, otherwise read `:help usr_40` and `:help usr_41`.

Answer (score 11):

There's also a nice vim script: [DetectIndent](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1171) which tries to detect the indentation of a file that you open.
It's very handy if you work with many files with different coding style.

I use an autocommand in my *.vimrc*:

```
:autocmd BufReadPost * :DetectIndent
```

Answer (score 1):

To insert space characters whenever the tab key is pressed, set the 'expandtab' option:

```
:set expandtab
```

Next step is to control the number of space characters that will be inserted when the tab key is pressed, set the 'tabstop' option. For example, to insert 2 space for a tab, use:

```
:set tabstop=2
```

ref: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces