# vim colorcolumn when not file type

Tags: vim

This is what I currently have to make a line on the 81st column

```
"====[ Make the 81st column stand out ]=========================
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=magenta
set colorcolumn=81
```

How can I change this to not show this when I'm editing *.html files?

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1562645/2588818

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to create a file `~/.vim/ftplugin/html.vim` with

```
setlocal colorcolumn=
```

and make sure that you have enabled filetype plugins with

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

in your vimrc file.

Another way would be with an autocommand in your vimrc:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.html setlocal colorcolumn=
```