# How to turn off tab indicators for a specific file type in vim

Tags: vim

currently I have this in my .vimrc

```
:set listchars=tab:\|\
```

I would like to turn this off when working with csv files because it interferes with the vim csv plugin.

How do I achieve this in my .vimrc?

Comment: Run `:set nolist` to disable all special character.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562633/setting-vim-whitespace-preferences-by-filetype

Comment: thank Xin Huang however although it seems similar, that solution didn't work for my scenerio

Comment: what did not work, what have you tried (from Xin Huang's link) show your autocmd. try running " :verbose set listchars? " what does it show ?

Comment: The link from Xin should help, it will be something like, im not sure about the Filetype for csv.
`autocmd Filetype csv set nolist`

Comment: posted a better method as an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42275093/3018289

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your .vimrc to not show tab characters on csv files

`au BufNewFile,BufRead *.csv set nolist`

Comment: still doesn't solve the issue, [here](http://i.imgur.com/DbfT9JM.png) is a screenshot