# How to make tab spaces in vim varies according to file?

Tags: vim, neovim, macvim

I would like to use 4 spaces for each tab in files in python, c++, and others, but I would like to set it to 2 spaces in javascript and typescript files. Is there a way to do customize it in vimrc?

```
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 " while using py, cpp and others
set tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 " while using js, ts
```

What I did is manually change the code above. If I am writing python, I change it to 4 and when I am writing javascript, I change it to 2.

Update: Solved, feel free to check [Setting Vim whitespace preferences by filetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562633/setting-vim-whitespace-preferences-by-filetype)

Comment: Check `:h autocmd` and `:h ftplugin`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+tab+filetype

Comment: @phd thanks, it works.